# Using std::function in std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, std-function

I want use a std::function in std::map, follow the code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>

class MyClass {
    ...
    std::function<void()> Callback();
    std::map<std::string, Callback> my_map;
    ...
}
```

std::map receive a Key and a T, but a not knew whats mistake in my code, him no access the std::map functions(insert, end, find...)

Using typedef, him run.But why std::function not run?

I firts place: whats the problem?

Before: How to solve it? --code sample please =D;

Thanks by help

Comment: How do you insert a member method into the my_map?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've declared `Callback` to be a function (returning `std::function`), not a type. You need a type to declare what you're storing in the map. I guess you want

```
typedef std::function<void()> Callback;
```

Comment: Working fine after typedef.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way of declaring map, having class function ptr.

- If you don't want to use `typedef`.

  `std::map<std::string, void (MyClass::*)()> my_map;`